# Not permanent crash of MediaCodec configure method

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I catched android.media.MediaCodec$CodecException: Error 0x80001001 sometimes when I try to configure a MediaCodec in next way:

```
MediaFormat outputFormat = new MediaFormat();
outputFormat.setString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME, COMPRESSED_AUDIO_FILE_MIME_TYPE);
outputFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT, 2);
outputFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE, frequency);
outputFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_AAC_PROFILE, MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.AACObjectLC);
outputFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, COMPRESSED_AUDIO_FILE_BIT_RATE);
outputFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_MAX_INPUT_SIZE, 0);

MediaCodec codec = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(COMPRESSED_AUDIO_FILE_MIME_TYPE);
codec.configure(outputFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
codec.start();
```

Full log of crash:

```
E/OMXMaster﹕ A component of name 'OMX.qcom.audio.decoder.aac' already exists, ignoring this one.
E/ACodec﹕ [OMX.google.aac.encoder] configureCodec returning error -38
E/ACodec﹕ signalError(omxError 0x80001001, internalError -2147483648)
E/MediaCodec﹕ Codec reported err 0x80001001, actionCode 0, while in state 3
E/MediaCodec﹕ configure failed with err 0x80001001, resetting...
I/OMXClient﹕ Using client-side OMX mux.
E/OMXMaster﹕ A component of name 'OMX.qcom.audio.decoder.aac' already exists, ignoring this one.
```

So the problem, as I understood, appear in native code. But it appears only on some devices - for example on Nexus 7 with Android 5.1, while Nexus 10 with the same android version works perfectly.

It seems I found the sources of MediaCodec and place where crash is. Here the link http://sourceforge.net/p/opencore-amr/vo-aacenc/ci/2418ead75aa9cdaf01cb4286f38fb7be2d48bd8d/tree/aacenc/SoftAACEncoder2.cpp#l362.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there was a problem with WAV header of my audio file. I ran a converting in asynctask, but wrote a header after its running. So, sometimes I tried to convert a wav file without header. Because of I pull some parameters from the wav header (like a frequency etc.), I got a 0 values. As result, MediaCodec could not be configured and crashed.